# Steps to update certificate in edge servers

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate-authority, exchange-2013, exchange-hybrid, microsoft-edge

Onprem mailbox servers is in exchange 2013 and edge servers in dmz. Can someone please share the steps to renew third part cert in edge servers. I am unable to find a ms article. Please help

Comment: **We have a hybrid environment** - Hybrid what?

Comment: Did you follow Louisl's suggestion to update the certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you need to bind this certificate to SMTP service and then recreate the edge subscription to use it.
See this article for help:https://ficilitydotnet.wordpress.com/2013/04/26/smtp-certificate-renewal-and-edge-subscription/